# Dynamic cookbook with chef

Tags: chef-infra

I'm trying to create a recipe that unzip some files then the behavior is depend on the content of the zipfile.
but I can't figure put how to overcome the Compile vs Converge phase.

The directories are not exists before the recipe is executed so the command to get the sub directories must be inside a ruby block to fetch the data in runtime.

But once the command is inside the ruby block I can't "read" the new values of the variables or attributes.

here is a sample:

```
ruby_block 'update patch attributes' do
   block do
      OPatchPath="#{node[:oracle][:rdbms][:ora_home]}/OPatch/#{Patch_No}"
      Subdir_list = Dir.glob("#{OPatchPath}/*/")

      Subdir_list.each do |dir|
         Subdir_list.map! {|dir| dir.sub("#{OPatchPath}/", "")}
         Subdir_list.map! {|dir| dir.sub('/', "")}
      end

      node.set[:oracle][:rdbms][:oracle_patch_list]=Subdir_list
   end
end

## if there are no directories with numberes 
if Subdir_list.find { |e| /^\d+$/ =~ e } == nil
   do something
else 
   if Subdir_list.count == 2
      do something else
   else
      do some other something
   end
end
```

I did a deep research online and tried a lot of suggestions include using lazy, node.set, node.default node.run_state with no luck.
what am I missing?
any suggestions?

Thanks, Ofir.

Answer (score 0):

This is a compile vs. converge issue, you can see https://coderanger.net/two-pass/ for a more detailed overview but tl;dr is that the code inside the ruby_block happens after the code outside the ruby_block even though that may not match the order in the file. You'll probably need to make a custom resource.

Comment: Can you give an example for how to use custom resource to solve this problem?
Can I use a custom resource in a ruby code?